# shinyDirButton not recognizing folders with latin1 encoding

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm using the shinyDirButton to select folders in my device memory, but when I open the tag in my app it doesn't recognize folders with not UTF-8 characthers, like "dimensão". I've searched all over the documentation but didn't found any way to consider the folder name's encoding.